# How do you import a CSV and convert from list into a string in Netlogo?

Tags: string, list, csv, netlogo

**How do I import data from a CSV file and convert it line-by-line into a string?** Whenever I try, I get error messages that it is still a list or a list of lists. I am trying to copy the example given in the Netlogo User Manual for reading a file one line per tick (see below). I created a simpler example. THANKS!!

My code:

```
extensions [CSV]
globals [date]


to setup
  clear-all
  file-close-all
  file-open "S&PDate.csv"
  set date current-date
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if file-at-end? [stop]
  set date current-date
  tick
end

to-report current-date 
  file-open "S&PDate.csv"
  let result csv:from-row file-read-line 
  while [ not file-at-end? ] [
    let row csv:from-row file-read-line
    set result (map result row)
  ]
  file-close
  report result
end
```

[NetLogo example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q36xY.png)

Comment: Post your code not image

Answer (score 1):

Saad is right, and you may want to have a look at the asking guidelines on making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Are you wanting string output so that your monitors look nice? If so, would this do the trick?

```
extensions [ csv ]
globals [ dates ]

to setup
  ca
  set dates csv:from-file "example_strings.csv"
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  if ticks < length dates [
    print current-date
    tick
  ]  
end

to-report current-date
  report csv:to-string ( list item ticks dates )
end
```

Comment: Ok, I will post a new question with a simpler example. Thanks for the feedback.